# headerDividersEnabled not respected on some devices

Tags: android, android-layout

I've tried this on a few devices but it looks like the `headerDividersEnabled` property I have set to true for my listview isn't respected on all devices. As an example I've uploaded how the app renders on my different devices. Header is the blue bar plus join our tournaments section. Only the first listed device properly displays the header divider as specified.

**Samsung Galaxy S3**
Android 4.4.4 - cyanogenmod 11-20150831-SNAPSHOT-XNG3CAO3FN-d2lte
https://i.stack.imgur.com/InVzI.jpg

**Samsung Galaxy S3**
Android 4.2.2 - cyanogenmod 10.1.3-d2att
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkjfF.jpg

**LG Lucid 2**
Android 4.1.2 - Xperion_l1v_11-2-2014
https://i.stack.imgur.com/efOmQ.jpg